# How to export a Dataset to JSON or CSV?

Tags: dataset, wolfram-cloud

I am getting wolfram CDF format from this,

```
beta = APIFunction[{"tablename" -> "String"},ResourceData[ResourceObject[#tablename] ]& ]
co = CloudDeploy[beta, Permissions->"Public"]
```

Response:

```
Dataset[{<|"Name" -> "Aachen", "ID" -> "1", "NameType" -> "Valid", "Classification" -> "L5", "Mass" -> Quantity[21, "Grams"], "Fall" -> "Fell", "Year" -> DateObject[{1880}, "Year", "Gregorian", -5.], "Coordinates" -> GeoPosition[{50.775, 6.08333}]|>, <|"Name" -> "Aarhus", "ID" -> "2", "NameType" -> "Valid", "Classification" -> "H6", "Mass" -> Quantity[720, "Grams"], "Fall" -> "Fell", "Year" -> DateObject[{1951}, "Year", "Gregorian", -5.], "Coordinates" -> GeoPosition[{56.18333, 10.23333}]|>, <|"Name" -> "Abee", "ID" -> "6", "NameType" -> "Valid", "Classification" -> "EH4", "Mass" -> Quantity[107000, "Grams"], "Fall" -> "Fell", "Year" -> DateObject[{1952}, "Year", "Gregorian", -5.], "Coordinates" -> GeoPosition[{54.21667, -113.}]|>, <|"Name" -> "Acapulco", "ID" -> "10", "NameType" -> "Valid", "Classification" -> "Acapulcoite", "Mass" -> Quantity[1914, "Grams"], "Fall" -> "Fell", "Year" -> DateObject[{1976}, "Year", "Gregorian", -5.], "Coordinates" -> GeoPosition[{16.88333, -99.9}]|>, <|"Name" -> "Achiras", "ID" -> "370", "NameType" -> "Valid", "Classification" -> "L6", "Mass" -> Quantity[780, "Grams"], "Fall" -> "Fell", "Year" -> DateObject[{1902}, "Year", "Gregorian", -5.], "Coordinates" -> GeoPosition[{-33.16667, -64.95}]|> }]
```

I need this in a JSON format, I tried to convert it using URLexecute it didn't work

Does anyone know any pythonic or wolfram way to convert this into JSON or CSV?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are getting is not "CDF format" but a Mathematica `Dataset`. You should also note that you are trying to convert and serve a dataset that has 45716 entries. This might well run into limits (cputime, memory, transfered data) of an `APIFunction`. I am also not sure whether WRI will allow you to provide a possibility to download complete resource-data datasets, you would have to check their legal conditions. Finally you should note that there is already a possibility to download the whole dataset from https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/Meteorite-Landings, although the JSON that is delivered looks a bit special (it is a Mathematica expression expressed as JSON arrays, probably not what one would expect...).

Using the following code in your API function should convert the first 10 entries into a JSON equivalent of the `Dataset`:

```
api=APIFunction[{"tablename" -> "String"},ExportString[
 (Take[ResourceData[ResourceObject[#tablename]],10] // Normal) //. {
 a_Association :> Normal[a],
 q_Quantity :> QuantityMagnitude[q],
 d_DateObject :> d@"Year",
 g_GeoPosition :> {Latitude[g], Longitude[g]}
}, "JSON","Compact"->True] &,"String"]
```

What it does is to convert the `Dataset` into a list of rules using `Normal` (as `ExportString[_,"JSON"]` can not directly digest the `Dataset`). It then converts all elements that can not directly be exported to something equivalent that can be exported. Check the documentation for more details about the various data types and functions used. I also added the option `"Compact"->True` for `ExportString` which will make the result more compact (it avoids formatting with tabs and newlines) and an additional explicit format argument to `APIFunction` which will make the `APIFunction` return the JSON string itself instead of a Mathematica string containing the JSON string (which basically means an extra set of `"`). This way the `APIFunction` should behave more like one would expect.

As you seem to have problems to get the APIFunction to work, here is example code which shows how to deploy the APIFunction:

```
co = CloudDeploy[api, Permissions -> "Public"];
```

... check that it works correctly (note that you need to include the space in `"tablename"` and URL-encode it, which `URLBuild` will conveniently do for you):

```
Import[URLBuild[co, {"tablename" -> "Meteorite Landings"}], "RawJSON"]
```

... and finally remove the public api (you probably don't want it to linger around and let others consume your cloud credits):

```
DeleteFile[co]
```

One more tip when working with such code: I would only deploy some functionality to the cloud once it works locally. In your case you could for example test the conversion to JSON entirely on your local machine without spending any cloud credits and resulting in a much faster loop while developing/testing:

```
data = ResourceData[ResourceObject["Meteorite Landings"]]

Length[data]

Take[data, 10]

ExportString[(Take[data, 10] // Normal) //. {a_Association :> 
  Normal[a], q_Quantity :> QuantityMagnitude[q], 
  d_DateObject :> d@"Year", 
  g_GeoPosition :> {Latitude[g], Longitude[g]}}, "JSON"]
```

Comment: This could also be done inside of `ExportString[ds, "RawJSON", "ConversionFunction" -> Normal, 
 "ConversionRules" -> {q_Quantity :> <|"mag" -> QuantityMagnitude[q], 
     "unit" -> QuantityUnit[q]|>, d_DateObject :> d@"Year", 
   g_GeoPosition :> <|"lat" -> Latitude[g], "long" -> Longitude[g]|>}]`

Comment: Hi I am very new to Wolfram alpha I tried 
`gamma = APIFunction[ExportString[(ResourceData[ResourceObject[#tablename]] // Normal) //. {
 a_Association :> Normal[a],
 q_Quantity :> QuantityMagnitude[q],
 d_DateObject :> d@"Year",
 g_GeoPosition :> {Latitude[g], Longitude[g]}
}, "JSON"] &
 ]` 

the API didnt return anything except the function definition

Comment: The api accepts tablename parameter = "Meteorite Landings"

Comment: @albert-retey can you let me know what am I doing wrong

Comment: Also tried ExportForm getting following error response on it

On trying exportForm I am getting error

    `CloudDeploy[ExportForm[ResourceData[ResourceObject["MeteoriteLandings"]],"JSON"]]
    ]
    
    Dataset: Dataset of the given form could not be exported as format "JSON"`

Comment: @Mk47: please see my updated answer...

Comment: @albert-retey I am getting values with tabs and newlines in them which isn't really of any use  `"[\n\t{\n\t\t\"Name\":\"Aachen\",\n\t\t\"ID\":\"1\",\n\t\t\"NameType\":\"Valid\",\n\t\t\"Classification\":\"L5\",\n\t\t\"Mass\":21,\n\t\t\"Fall\":\"Fell\",\n\t\t\"Year\":1880,\n\t\t\"Coordinates\" :..... "Year\":1920,\n\t\t\"Coordinates\":[\n\t\t\t-3.086667e1,\n\t\t\t-6.455e1\n\t\t]\n\t}\n]"`

Comment: What exactly are you doing to get that string and what are you trying to achieve? it is just the plain text form of the JSON string. In Mathematica, you can import that string with `ImportString["...","RawJSON"]` to get an association. In most other languages there is similar functionality to parse a JSON string into some data structure...

Comment: Actually you can avoid all the tabs and newlines by using the option `"Compact" -> True` for the Export, which I have added to my answer. It mainly avoids sending unnecessary data but doesn't make a difference about how you would treat the result, though....

Comment: I also added an explicit format argument to `APIFunction` as I realized that the default would return a Mathematica string which means an extra set of `"` and the explict newline and tabs you were seeing. This should make it more straightforward to use the api as it then directly returns just the JSON string...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Dude you are awesome is there any way I can contact you? I might have something for you if you are interested.